# Jquery not working with Bootstrap radio button

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Hello all I have form like

```
    <form class="form-inline">
         <div class="row" style="margin-left: 6px;">
             <label class="radio-inline" style="margin-left: 10px;">
             <input class="radio" type="radio" name="alluser" id="alluser" value="option1" checked="chacked" />
             All </label>
             <div class="form-group">
                 <label for="inputStandard" class="col-lg-2 control-label">
                     <input class="radio" type="radio" name="tomobile" id="tomobile" value="option2"  />
                 </label>
                 <div class="col-lg-10">
                    <input type="text" id="mobileno" name="mobileno" class="form-control" placeholder="Mobile Number" disabled="disabled" />
                 </div>
             </div>
        </div>
    <form>
```

i have writtent Jquery code like

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

     $("#tomobile").click(function(){
        $("#alluser").prop("checked", false);
         $("#mobileno").attr("disabled", false);
         $("#tomobile").attr("checked", "checked");
     });

      $("#alluser").click(function(){
         $("#mobileno").attr("disabled", true);
         $("#mobileno").prop("checked", false);
     });
});
```

this code is working for textbox only. it enables or disable textbox but not uncheck radio button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you set the name="" attribute to the same value for the two radio buttons, then only one can be checked at a time. If you do this, then your jquery can look like:

```
 $("#tomobile").click(function(){
     $("#mobileno").attr("disabled", false);
 });

 $("#alluser").click(function(){
     $("#mobileno").attr("disabled", true);
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Your ID name was wrong:

```
 $("#alluser").click(function(){
     $("#mobileno").attr("disabled", true);
     $("#mobileno").prop("checked", false);
 });
```

Needs to be:

```
 $("#alluser").click(function(){
     $("#mobileno").attr("disabled", true);
     $("#tomobile").prop("checked", false);
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Your id on the last click function is wrong

```
$("#mobileno").prop("checked", false);
```

should be :

```
$("#tomobile").prop("checked", false);
```

heres a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6A5u5/)